# Is there an application for measuring uploaded and downloaded data?

Tags: 15.04, downloads, upload

I want an application to count amount of data uploaded and downloaded and the speed of each.

Comment: I like to use `slurm` to show live traffic, as well as averages and min and max **while it is running**.  `ntop` is a great *daemon* that will allow you to see running stats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gnome System Monitor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-system-monitor/) [image: Install Gnome System Monitor] does the job for me. Its “Resources” tab contains a network history section, that you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of network monitor tab]

On a very basic level you can also look at `/sys/class/net/*/statistics/[rt]x_bytes` for total amounts of bytes transferred for each network interface since boot.

Comment: Can I view it separately?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iftop`. It can show you the download/upload speeds along with the amount of data downloaded/uploaded in that `iftop` session.

Install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install iftop
```

For example, to check the upload/download on interface `eth0`:

```
sudo iftop -i eth0
```

Check `man iftop` to get more idea.

On the other hand if you are interested in process-wise upload/download measurements, then use `nethogs`:

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

Run it as:

```
sudo nethogs eth0
```

Check `man nethogs` to get more idea.